# Java generic Enum

Tags: java, enums

For my icons in Swing i've different enums like:

```
    public enum Icon32 {
    STOP("resources/icons/x32/stop.ico"),
    RUN("resources/icons/x32/run.ico");
    private File path;

    private Icon32(String path) {
        this.path = new File(path);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return path;
    }
```

or

```
public enum Tab {
    XML("resources/icons/x32/tab/tab_1.ico"), QR("resources/icons/x32/tab/tab_2.ico"),ABOUT("resources/icons/x32/tab/tab_3.ico");
    private File path;

    private Tab(String path) {
        this.path = new File(path);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return path;
    }

}
```

I've created an abstract implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractImageType {

private File path;

private AbstractImageType(String path) {
    this.path = new File(path);
}

public File getFile() {
    return path;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return path.toString();
}
```

}

But Enum is not possible to extend:

```
Syntax error on token "extends", implements expected
```

Now my question, is it possible to make a generic class "AbstractImageType" whos implementing the method(s) and constructor? so i've only to insert the Enum values?

Something like this:

```
 public enum Icon32 extends AbstractImageType {
    STOP("resources/icons/x32/stop.ico"),
    RUN("resources/icons/x32/run.ico");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums in java do not support inheritence from classes because each `enum` is actually a simple class that extends `Enum`. Since multiple inheritance is not supported you cannot create base class for 2 enums.

You can either stop using enums for this purpose, i.e. switch to regular classes or use delegation to create File, i.e. utility that accepts enum member and returns `File` instance.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your `AbstractImageType` an interface and have your enums implement that.

```
public interface AbstractImageType {

    File getFile();
}

public enum Icon32 implements AbstractImageType  {
    STOP("resources/icons/x32/stop.ico"),
    RUN("resources/icons/x32/run.ico");
    private File path;

    private Icon32(String path) {
        this.path = new File(path);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use any kind of inheritance for enums, since it would break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Java 8 will have [default implementations](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/java-8-now-you-have-mixins/) of methods in interfaces, but they probably won't extend to constructors.

The best you can do is probably to generate the code, such as with [custom templates](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ) in eclipse.